# Iphone thumbnail not showing

Tags: html, iphone, macos, shopify

My issue is video thumbnail not showing on iPhone

**Blank white thumbnail image Picture**:
[Click to View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PBwH.png)

**here is code:**

```
<video width="100%" src="{{section.settings.mp4url}}" preload="auto"  controls="true" loop  playsinline></video>
```

I have searched for 2 days tried all solutions on platforms but not worked single one.

Comment: This is not really enough to go on, as there could be some code above this, or in another file that is impacting it. Which theme are you using? Has it always been like that, or did it happen recently?

Comment: I think you'll find this useful: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.